# PyQt QTextCharFormat mixing the font

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am going to make the selected text italic in PyQt text editor

**Scenario 1**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Scenario 2**

[image]

[image]

[image]

The images are pretty self explaining.You will probably say then why don't you

just you textEdit.setFontItalic() then actually I am already using that but

textEdit doesn't have overline and strikeout while QTextCharFormat has ton of

properties but it has it's problems

textEdit.setCurrentCharFormat(),setCurrentFont(),setStyleSheet,setFont() but all

cause the same problem as QTextCharFormat

is there a way around this

thanks

Comment: I have also use Html tags

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I have got the answer.

instead of `cursor.setCharFormat()` use `cursor.mergeCharFormat()`